# Using the ActionProvider of a File - Eclipse CNF

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin which creates a custom `Package Explorer` that represent the underlying file system hierarchy in a different hierarchy (some sort of virtual folders).

I've managed to create the hierarchy by implementing `ITreeContentProvider`.The final node should represent a file with all its actions (open, copy, rename...), it works great when I  return an Instance of `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File` but if I create a `delegate/proxy` class which implements the `IFile` interface I see the action but when I click on one of them Eclipse freezes.

Anyway, I guess I'll need to implement my own `CommonActionProvider`. my question is:
**How can I add the same action to a node, that will represent actions on file, is there some FileActionProvider?**

[image]

I'm following the following tutorial: [tutorial](http://scribbledideas.blogspot.co.il/)

**UPDATE**

I've tried messing with the adapters as @greg-449, suggested.However none of them gave me the full menu, the biggest menu I got was but implementing the `IAdaptable` interface and delegating the `getAdapter()` to the instance of my IFile. but doing so the double click to open file is not working, and most important the rename,delete,move are not here

[image: menu I got by delegating the getAdapter]

menu I got by delegating the `getAdapter()`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to implement `IFile` you should use an `IAdapterFactory` to provide an adapter from your UI class to the underlying `IFile`.

Declare the adapter factory using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters` extension point:

```xml
 <extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
     <factory 
        class="com.xyz.MyFileAdapterFactory" 
        adaptableType="com.xyz.MyFile">
        <adapter type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
     </factory>
  </extension>
```

The adapter factory class methods would look something like:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType)
{
  if (adaptableObject instanceof MyFile)
   {
     // TODO get the IFile from MyFile
     return ifile;
   }

  return null;
}

@Override
public Class<?> [] getAdapterList()
{
  return new  Class<?> [] {IFile.class};
}
```

You might also need to register for `IResource` to get all menu items working.

You can also register the factory using the `IAdapterManager` interface.

Comment: just to be sure the `com.xyz.MyFile` is the same object that I return from the `getChildren` method within the `ITreeContentProvider`? Secondly, I did so but I get only `Source` and `Generate` there. Moreover, non of the `IAdapterFactory` methods being invoked

Comment: Check you have the extension point declaration is correct, I had it wrong to begin with.

Comment: It looks like it is configured correctly, if I remove the extension point I don't get the menu with the `Source` and `Generate`, but in any case the adapter's method are not invoked

Comment: OK if you get something the declaration is OK, just having the adapter declared is enough for the menu to show, the actual code is not called until the menu item is selected. Other menu items may want an adapter to IResource or org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping

Comment: I've updated my question, would you mind to take a look. thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any globally defined rename, delete and move actions, you will have to add your own. Although many things work with IAdaptable a few things only look for the IAdapterFactory.